# Adding nodes inside svg rect using d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have drawn four svg rect diagram...with different colors....
I'm trying to add node inside of those svg rect...but I'm getting only the svg rect without node inside them...I know that I have done something wrong  with data...

But I'm not able to figure them out..I'm just one month old to D3..please advice me on this....

If you run the  code below you can see my mistake....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../D3/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>

</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var width = 500,
            height = 500;


        var nodes = [
     { x: width / 3, y: height / 2 }
     //{ x: 2 * width / 3, y: height / 1 },
     //{ x: 3 * width / 3, y: height / 2 },
     //{ x: 4 * width / 3, y: height / 2 }
        ];



        var force = d3.layout.force()
                     .size([width, height])
                     .nodes(nodes)



        var svgcontainer = d3.select("body")
                             .append("svg")
                             .attr("width", 1000)
                             .attr("height", 900);


        var rectdata = [{ "x": 50, "y": 70, "width": 600, "height": 150,"rx":80,"ry":80,"fill":"skyblue"},
                       { "x": 50, "y": 260, "width": 200, "height": 400, "rx": 80, "ry": 90, "fill": "palegreen" },
                       { "x": 440, "y": 260, "width": 200, "height": 400, "rx": 80, "ry": 90, "fill": "orange" },
                       { "x": 50, "y": 700, "width": 600, "height": 150, "rx": 80, "ry": 80, "fill": "brown" }];


        var svgrect = svgcontainer.selectAll("rect").data(rectdata).enter().append("rect");



        var node = svgcontainer.selectAll('.node')
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter().append('rect')
                      .attr('class', 'node');

        force.on('end', function () {

            svgrect.attr("x", function (d, i) { return d.x; })
                   .attr("y", function (d, i) { return d.y; })
                   .attr("rx", function (d, i) { return d.rx; })
                   .attr("ry", function (d, i) { return d.ry; })
                   .attr("width", function (d, i) { return d.width; })
                   .attr("height", function (d, i) { return d.height; })
                   .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return d.fill; });


        });


        force.start();


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't giving the `node` any attributes. I take it you want a circle and not a rect :

```
 var node = svgcontainer.selectAll('.node')
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter().append('circle')
                      .attr('class', 'node')
                      .attr('x', function(d){ console.log(d); return d.x})
                      .attr('y', function(d){ return d.y})
                      .attr('r', 10)
                      .attr('transform', function(d){
                      return 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')'
                      })
```

Notice the translate at the bottom. If you are using the force layout in D3, the tick function should take care of this, but it looks like you don't have one, so you have to insert it after you create the nodes.

If you didn't want circles and wanted rectangles then this should do :

```
 var nodeRect = svgcontainer.selectAll('.nodeRect')
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter().append('rect')
                      .attr('class', 'nodeRect')
                      .attr('x', function(d){ console.log(d); return d.x})
                      .attr('y', function(d){ return d.y})
                      .attr('width', 100)
                       .attr('height', 50)
                      .attr('transform', function(d){
                      return 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')'
                      })
```

Working fiddle with both : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/n13kqvw9/

```js
        var width = 500,
            height = 500;


        var nodes = [
     { x: width / 3, y: height / 2 }
     //{ x: 2 * width / 3, y: height / 1 },
     //{ x: 3 * width / 3, y: height / 2 },
     //{ x: 4 * width / 3, y: height / 2 }
        ];



        var force = d3.layout.force()
                     .size([width, height])
                     .nodes(nodes)



        var svgcontainer = d3.select("body")
                             .append("svg")
                             .attr("width", 1000)
                             .attr("height", 900);


        var rectdata = [{ "x": 50, "y": 70, "width": 600, "height": 150,"rx":80,"ry":80,"fill":"skyblue"},
                       { "x": 50, "y": 260, "width": 200, "height": 400, "rx": 80, "ry": 90, "fill": "palegreen" },
                       { "x": 440, "y": 260, "width": 200, "height": 400, "rx": 80, "ry": 90, "fill": "orange" },
                       { "x": 50, "y": 700, "width": 600, "height": 150, "rx": 80, "ry": 80, "fill": "brown" }];


        var svgrect = svgcontainer.selectAll("rect").data(rectdata).enter().append("rect");



        var node = svgcontainer.selectAll('.node')
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter().append('circle')
                      .attr('class', 'node')
                      .attr('x', function(d){ console.log(d); return d.x})
                      .attr('y', function(d){ return d.y})
                      .attr('r', 10)
                      .attr('transform', function(d){
                      return 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')'
                      })
                      
        var nodeRect = svgcontainer.selectAll('.nodeRect')
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter().append('rect')
                      .attr('class', 'nodeRect')
                      .attr('x', function(d){ console.log(d); return d.x})
                      .attr('y', function(d){ return d.y})
                      .attr('width', 100)
                       .attr('height', 50)
                      .attr('transform', function(d){
                      return 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')'
                      })

        force.on('end', function () {

            svgrect.attr("x", function (d, i) { return d.x; })
                   .attr("y", function (d, i) { return d.y; })
                   .attr("rx", function (d, i) { return d.rx; })
                   .attr("ry", function (d, i) { return d.ry; })
                   .attr("width", function (d, i) { return d.width; })
                   .attr("height", function (d, i) { return d.height; })
                   .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return d.fill; });


        });


        force.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```